# What happens when the table storage configured with orleans suddenly fails or gets dropped?

Tags: .net, orleans

We have several constantly running grains and are making heavy usage of reminders in our code. Currently our setup points to azure table storage for orleans to store its metadata and this is where I see the reminders are being stored. What happens if for some reason this table or storage account suddenly gets deleted? Does orleans cache or store some of this data locally that it can restore from automatically? Or are the reminders wiped out permanently? How can they be brought back in a disaster?

Comment: Might be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718574/orleans-what-happens-when-system-storage-is-down-or-inaccessible?rq=2